# Configuration property "url" is not defined error while trying to start a NestJs microservice

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, nestjs-config

WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'local' did not match any deployment config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'local' is ambiguous.
WARNING: See https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
^
Error: Configuration property "url" is not defined

I have cloned a project. They are using older versions of packages. I downgraded my node.js and npm as recommended by them. I used to --legacy-peer-deps flag to install all the dependencies. I added the yaml file to the project to add and run the docker container provided by them. I am getting the above error when I try to start any microservice.

Comment: Check the Node Config documentation for examples of defining and accessing properties: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.